# How to add another item to databound DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList` control in my ASP.NET C# web application that reads from `SqlDataSource`. I have a list of items that are displayed, but I want to add more text to the first item to say "Please select department" with `value == 0`.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList
   ID="DropDownList1"
   DataSourceID="sdsdepartment"
   runat="server"
   DataTextField="department_name"
   DataValueField="deptid"
></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource
   ID="sdsdepartment"
   runat="server"
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:blabla %>"
   SelectCommand="SELECT [department_name], [deptid] FROM [DEPARTMENT]"
></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your SelectCommand to:

```
SELECT 'Please select department' as [department_name], 0 as [deptid]
UNION
SELECT [department_name], [deptid] FROM [DEPARTMENT]
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Page_Load add the following line.

DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select department", "0"));

Answer (score 0):

This will be very simple

```
<asp:DropDownList
ID="DropDownList1"
DataSourceID="sdsdepartment"
runat="server"
DataTextField="department_name"
DataValueField="deptid"
AppendDataBoundItems="True" // set this property to True
>
<asp:ListItem Text="select Department" Value="0"></asp:ListItem> //here add one default item

</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource
ID="sdsdepartment"
runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:blabla %>"SelectCommand="SELECT [department_name], 
[deptid] FROM [DEPARTMENT]"
></asp:SqlDataSource>
```